# Routing traffic through TOR

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity

Just would like to ask if its possible to route traffic through windows on TOR. I tried with the vidilia control panel but it seems that the support has been discontinued. Cannot find much information online as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm what you mean by "route traffic through windows on Tor"? Do you mean a) you want everything on your PC - i.e. all the Windows apps that use your connection - to be anonymised; b) you want the websites you look at with your browser to be anonymised; c) you want to help other people out by routing *their* internet traffic through your PC? (i.e. Run a relay.)

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I am choosing a).

Comment: The safest option would be to use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/about/index.en.html) (a live, Tor-based OS), rather than attempting to use Tor under Windows. There's an interesting related thread [here](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4209/is-using-tor-on-windows-dangerous).

Comment: It is quite hard to tell what you're asking here. Do you want to use the Tor Browser Bundle to tunnel your traffic? Which traffic would that be? What exactly are you triying to achieve? Please [edit your question](https://tor.stackexchange.com/posts/7298/edit) and insert more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways of doing this, one way is [Tortilla](https://github.com/CrowdStrike/Tortilla).

[Whonix gateway](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Other_Operating_Systems#Windows-Whonix-Workstation) can also be used for this.

A router with custom firmware that includes tor transparent routing.
[WNR3500L](http://www.netgear.no/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/WNR3500L.aspx) router supports it through for example [tomato USB firmware](http://tomatousb.org/)

A raspberry pi set up as [onionpi](https://learn.adafruit.com/onion-pi/overview) can also route all traffic.

Or a second pc with for example Debian, installed as a middlebox for tor.
See [examples here](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy).

Just keep in mind windows is not considered secure because it's closed source, and can leak in many ways, but still - to answer your question - yes it can be done.